# How to make available a salesforce app on play store and how users can get credentials after downloading the app?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have a business scenario where I need to build a salesforce app and make it available on play store so that any customer can download and use that.My doubt is if any customer downloads it then he should have the credential to login.how can they get user credentials to login?

Comment: Your question headline and description are a bit not in sync, if you can modify it, that will help others here. As for the details you requested -- If you are building a custom application and hosting on play store which requires users to authenticate themselves before they can use the features, then Yes, you will need the users to have credentials for this purpose. As for "how" can they get credentials, that needs to be created by system admins and shared with the users who want to use the app.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response..when we download any android app from play store we need to sign up with our mail account or by giving our email id for sign up like that here how can the user can sign up or get the credentials from admin?

Comment: Credentials for play store or any app store are different from what you need to access Salesforce features that you have built within your app.

Comment: can we enable self registration for customer portal so that after downloading the sf app user can sign up or login through the customer portal?

Comment: Yes you can, depending on how you want to implement your "app".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rolling up the details in comments here:

If you are building a custom application and hosting on play store which requires users to authenticate themselves before they can use the Salesforce features, then **Yes**, you will need the users to have credentials for this purpose. As for "how" can they get credentials, that needs to be created by system admins and shared with the users who want to use the app.

You can also customize the app to provide a self registration feature as when a user downloads the app, they can register themselves, instead a system admin providing them the access.

It all depends on what are your Business use case scenarios, but definitely there's a way to achieve what you need here.

If you are looking for portal self registration, you can find some pointers on the documentations.

- [Set Up Self-Registration for Your Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_selfreg_page.htm&type=5)
- [Self-Registration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_login_self_register.htm&type=5)
- [Create a Self-Registration Page](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/identity_external/units/identity_external_registration)

Comment: It helped..followed all the process..but after creating 1 user using this form it's not working again.created 1 user using self registration form and got details of that user in contact which is associated to account(Acc Name:'Customers').when I tried create again this error is showing"our request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator has been alerted."please help me out

Comment: It worked.As I was giving same emailId that's why it was throwing error..now it's solved.Thank you so much @Jayant Das.

Comment: Glad that it helped you.